# Integrate FB Chat in website

Tags: facebook

[image: screenshot]

I just saw someone implemented FB chat bubble in https://www.focusasia.xyz/. I tried searching for the documentation in FB on how to do it, but I got nothing.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do it? Or is it using some unofficial plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s most likely a messenger bot, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: @CBroe But it's not a bot answering the message, it's real people. I mean, I assume she's real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're actually using https://www.modernapp.co/, it's a paid service